# Regex match NOT surrounded by white spaces

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Context: I am building an interpreter for fun and need to implement a white space rule.

The rule is that regex must match plus "+" when NOT surrounded by spaces.
Here is a sample text:

```
a+b c +d g+ h i + j x+y
```

The plus between **a and b** should match as well as between **x and y**. I am new to regular expressions; however, I have tried the following regex:

```
\+(?<!\s)(?!\s)
```

Which for me means,

```
\+         find all "+" matches
(?<!\s)   (neg look behind) that don't have spaces behind
(?!\s)     (neg look ahead) that don't have spaces ahead
```

However when I run this on regex101, I am only able to match the first plus between **a and b**.

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly here. Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`\[a-zA-Z\]\+\[a-zA-Z\]`](https://regex101.com/r/MC6zxI/1)

or if there are more characters around + then use

```
[a-zA-Z]+\+[a-zA-Z]+
```

Update : you can use [`(?<!\s)[+)-](?!\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/Y5TfzA/2) by moving the matching symbol between lookbehind and lookahead conditions

Comment: Sorry, I should modify my example. That would work in the example above, but it needs to match on things like parenthesis. I could modify that to: [a-zA-Z\\(\\)]+\+[a-zA-Z\\(\\)]+ but I'd like to keep my code flexible enough to add more tokens without worrying about things like these. Since the rule is no whitespace surrounding, I'd like to figure out that way.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Thank you. I did not realize (though it makes sense) the location of the negative look behind mattered. Edit: If you could, please edit your answer from the answer found in the comments to reflect my question.